# How can I plot the figure with the number of pixel as a x-axis and the grayscale color as a y-axis in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, pytorch

I downloaded MNIST dataset and plot the first image of dataset with imshow function in grayscale.
Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms

# MNIST dataset 
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./data', 
                                           train=True, 
                                           download=True,
                                           transform=transform)

# Change data type : torch.Tensor -> numpy array
X = train_dataset.train_data.numpy()
y = train_dataset.train_labels.numpy()
print('Data size: ' + str(X.shape))

num_samples, height, width = X.shape 
dim = height * width

# Visualize MNIST data (1st digit)
plt.figure(1)
plt.imshow(X[0],cmap='gray_r')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('1st image label: 5')
```

And I got this figure

[image]

After reshape the 2-dimensional image vector to the one-dimensional vector, I would like to plot
the figure like this.

[image]

The x-axis represents pixel number, and the y-axis represents its pixel value as a grayscale color, and
the plot is like that, sort of spectrum.
I know how to reshape the vector, but I don't know how to make the plot.
Can I make the plot like the second one with function in matplotlib module? or in somewhere?

Comment: If you use `X[0].reshape((784, 1))` instead of `X[0].reshape(784)` you should be able to plot the image the same way you plotted your original 28x28 image, only now your y-axis is only 1 pixel strong. ( I hope I didn't missunderstand the question)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like the following code. I visualized the mnist digit numb

```
#load digits using the module load_digits()
digits = datasets.load_digits()

#visualize digits : 25 in 2D visualization
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(digits.images[25], cmap = plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.show()
```

Output is
[image]

Comment: That is 2-Dimensional image. I'm looking for the way to plot the second plot, with title '1st image vector'.   I tried to use imshow but it gives one black line, not a graph like that.  And I think you use Sklearn dataset, but I have to use data with numpy form